# When storing small data on server side, whats more efficient, DDBB's or files?

Tags: database, optimization

I'm writing a web application who needs to store data sent from one client, wait for other client to request and read it (on small intervalls, like 3 or 4 seconds) and then remove this data.

Currently im doing it saving this data to flat files but i'd like to know if it would be more efficient to write it to a database.

I know that usually it's more efficient to use a database but in this case i'll try to handle a lot of requests with small amounts of data on them.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my english :)

Comment: That is actually a very interesting question. I'm guessing that your best bet would be to build it both ways and stress-test it, but I'm interested to see what others provide for answers.  (And your English is  fine)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David's comment above. The question is how much I/O will you incur for each read/write. That can be affected by a lot of factors. I'm guessing the flat file option will be fastest, especially if your database is on a remote server and the data has to be sent over your internal network to read and write it.

Depending on how much data you have and how many requests you are handling, the fastest I/O would be to hold the data in memory. Of course, this is not very fault tolerant -- but that is also another consideration.  The DB would provide you better integrity (over using flat files) in the event of a failure -- but if that is not a consideration, you may want to just keep it in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm using django right now, i'll try to setup memcached to hold the data in memory using the django cache system. I am a relatively noob programmer so i don't know if this will be ok.